# ScrollToRef in ReactJS - Implicit type

Tags: reactjs, scroll

Im trying to use my menu to scroll on my one page. 
I found a lot of exemple ... but nothing work in my case :'(

I would like to use this function ...

```
const scrollToRef = (ref) => window.scrollTo({
    behavior: "smooth",
    top: ref.current.offsetTop
  });

function scrollToAboutMe(){
scrollToRef(refAboutme);
}


const Main: FunctionComponent = () => {

    const refAboutme = useRef()
    const refResume = useRef()
    const refPortfolio = useRef()
    const refContact = useRef()


    return (

            <div>
                <div>
                    <Landing/>
                    <Aboutme ref={refAboutme}/>
                    <Resume ref={refResume}/>
                    <Portfolio ref={refPortfolio}/>
                    <Contact ref={refContact}/>
                </div>


        </div>


    );
};

export default Main;
```

Sadly I have this error ( Parameter 'ref' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006 ) on this line : const scrollToRef = (ref)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
const scrollToRef = (ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | undefined>) => window.scrollTo({
  behavior: "smooth",
  top: ref.current.offsetTop
});
```

Comment: Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532 on top: ref.current.offsetTop

Comment: You inititize refs  `const refAboutme = useRef()`. So you have check is ref.current !== undefined and then call window.scrollTo